# Explicitly accessing module var from module function in revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I have a scope problem. I have the following code that implements the revealing module pattern:

```
myModule = function(){

  var foo = "ohai";

  function sayOhai(foo){
      alert(foo);
  };

  return{
    sayOhai : sayOhai
  };

}();

myModule.sayOhai("configData");
```

Which results in a Dialogue "configData".

However, I want the function sayOhai to say "ohai" using the defined var. Assumed i do not want to change the parameter name of sayOhai, how can i access foo's value within sayOhai? I tried `alert (this.foo)`, but that is undefined.

Again, this is a theoretical question, so changing `sayOhai(foo)` is not a solution i'm looking for. **The var's name and the method's parameter should stay the same**. So, from the scope of sayOhai, what's the full qualified name of var foo?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the function sayOhai to say "ohai" using the defined var. Assumed i do not want to change the parameter name of sayOhai, how can i access foo's value within sayOhai?

You simply can't. The var `foo` is shadowed by the inner function parameter with the same name.

Comment: I use _foo for the outer foo for this reason. Your parameter won't hit a name conflict, unless you use _'s in parameter names, which I don't think anyone does.

Comment: @Frug Sure, but I don't think that's what's being asked. BTW, is it a coincidence that we both have the same avatar?!

Comment: It's a weird Escher type of coincidence and weirded me out when I saw it too.

Comment: @Frug Nice to know other people enjoy the same kind of weirdness I do :)

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done as you have requested.

When you define `var foo = "ohai";` in the function and then return a closure, foo is now private.

In the function sayOhai, you have an argument with the same name as a variable declared above it in the lexical scope.

Therefore, the function's argument named foo always wins.